# Java Websocket Server Global DB connection

Tags: java, database, websocket, server

I'm trying to develop a Websocket based application using Java. Now I have a question: how to "permanently" connect the server endpoint to the database? (embedded with Netbeans newest version is Derby) I searched for quite a while seems all the Websocket tutorials are not related to database operation, although there are tutorials for Java connecting database. [*here a good one for example*](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/connect_to_a_database_using_java_code.html)

What I want is to keep a connection for all the incoming Websocket sessions instead of open one connection per each incoming session, which I think it may overhead too much. but it seems all the logics on the server side are triggered by those onOpen/onMessage/onClose/onError etc. If I put the conn onOpen, that may cause so many db connections at a time point. Can anyone suggest a suitable solution, for example, by the ServerApplicationConfig setting?

Comment: I'm trying to do open/close connections in a on-usage-base during the onMessage event. Hope it can make the performance better.